# Having a method accept different objects as an argument

Tags: java

First I will just put my sample code.

```
public class Shape {

    public String colour;

    public Shape(String colour) {
        this.colour = colour;
    }

}

public class Car {

    public String colour;

    public Car (String colour) {
        this.colour = colour;
    }

}

public class Colour {

    public static String getColour(Object item) {
        return item.**colour**;
    }

}
```

I've read other questions related to this, but I just can't seem to understand. I found their original code was just too complex for me to get around. So I tried to make as simple a code as possible. Anyway, I want getColour to accept both the Shape and Car object. If I use Object like I did in my example, the "colour" in bold is considered an error. The error I get is "colour cannot be resolved or is not a field". What's wrong?

Also, I've heard a lot of "static methods are bad" etc., is this a case of it being bad? Because I find if I don't make it static, then I need to duplicate getColour methods in both the Shape and Car classes. If I should avoid static methods, then please suggest another way to do this.

Comment: I recommend having both classes implement an interface like 'Colourable' and then you can use 'Colourable' as a parameter instead of Object.

Comment: Thanks guys. Wish I could check all answers as useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is the concept of [interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html):

```
public interface Colourable {
    String getColour();
    void setColour(String colour);
}
```

You should modify the `Shape` and `Car` classes:

```
public class Shape implements Colourable {
    public Shape(String colour) {
        this.colour = colour;
    }

    private String colour;

    public String getColour() {
        return colour;
    }

    public void setColour(String colour) {
        this.colour = colour;
    }
}
```

(note that I've made the `colour` field private; this is common practice and called [`encapsulation`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html))

You can then define your static method as

```
public static String getColour(Colourable item) {
    return item.getColour();
}
```

And static methods are definitely not bad, though in this case the method itself is a bit superfluous, because if you already have an `Colourable`, you know you can call `.getColour()` to get its color. A bit more useful would be the method

```
public static boolean isRed(Colourable item) {
    return "red".equals(item.getColour());
}
```

Comment: Sorry - mixing up languages.

Comment: Okay after reading up on interfaces, then reading your example, I'm still a bit confused here. The whole idea of my code was to eliminate duplicate code. That is, there is only one getColour() in my entire program. But it looks like since there is one in Shape now, there must be one in Car as well. Then if they are there anyway, what was the point of making the interface? Is there no other way to do what I want? I guess my original question is changed. How do I eliminate duplicate code in my case of getting colour for different object types?

Comment: Duplicate code isn't always a bad thing. In your original example, both classes have `public String colour;`. Does this also count as duplicate? Most Java programmers would say not - but they will say the same about my getters and setters. The only other option (in Java) is to have both classes inherit from a common superclass, but that has conceptual problems.

Comment: Hmm yes you are right about the conceptual problems which is why I began with two unrelated classes. So lets say in my original code, I had getColour() in both Shape and Car, and I got rid of the Colour class altogether. Would that be alright? But then if I add x more classes each with their own colour variable, I feel like I'm going to be adding x more getColour() methods.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your trying to use [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing), which isn't how Java works.

The easiest thing to do, IMHO, would be to define an interface to handle the color. E.g.:

```
public interface Colourful {
    public String getColour();
} 

public class Shape implements Colorful {

    private String colour;

    public Shape(String colour) {
        this.colour = colour;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColour() {
        return colour;
    }
}

public class Car {

    private String colour;

    public Car (String colour) {
        this.colour = colour;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColour() {
        return colour;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to change `Shape` and `Car`, you could use reflection to extract the `colour` field, but this is usually considered a bad idea, and you'd probably be better off not using it:

```
public static String getColour(Object o) {
    Field colourField;
    try {
        colourField = o.getClass().getField("colour");
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        // No such field
        return null;
    }

    Object colourValue;
    try {
        colourValue = colourField.get(o);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        // The field isn't public
        return null;
    }

    if (!(colourValue instanceof String)) {
        // The field isn't a String
        return null;
    }

    return (String) colourValue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can "unify" `Shape` and `Car`. There are two general approaches:

- [Inheritance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) and
- [Interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html)

Let's look at both.

**Inheritance**: When a class `Porsche` inherits (or, in Java syntax, `extends`) a class `Car`, you establish an "is-a" relationship. In this case: `Porsche` is-a `Car`. Now, the magic comes to work, when you use object references. You can now write something like this:

```
Car c = new Porsche();
```

Since a `Porsche` has everything, a `Car` has (plus some things on top), you can see a `Porsche` as a `Car` (each `Porsche` is a `Car`, but not each `Car` is a `Porsche`). Reading my last sentence carefully, it is obvious, that the following does not work and, in fact, produces a compile error:

```
Porsche p = new Car();
```

What you can now do is write a method, that expects a `Car` and pass in a `Porsche` (since every `Porsche` is a `Car`).

Coming back to your example. To get this working, you could define a common parent class for `Shape` and `Car`, let's call it `Colourable` and give it a method `public Colour getColour()`. Then, you could simply change your `getColour(Object item)` method to `getColour(Colourable c)`.

Remeber the thing I said about the "is-a" relation? Ask yourself: is each `Shape` a `Colourable`? Is each `Car` a `Colourable`? Why should `Car` and `Shape` both be in the same bucket (`Colourable`)? And what to do, if `Car` already has a parent class, e.g. `Vehicle`? This solution is sub-optimal.

**Interfaces**: This is, where interfaces come into play. Interfaces guarantee, that certain methods are present. Instead of defining a common parent class `Colourable`, you could simply write `Colourable` as an interface, containing the method `public Colour getColour()`. Now `Shape` and `Car` can `implements` this interface. This forces you to implement this method in both classes. The beauty: you can use interfaces just like classes. Meaning your implementation of `getColour(Colourable c)` does not need to change.

For more details, please read the provided tutorials on [Inheritance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) and [Interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html).

Answer (score 0):

The reason an error is thrown is that `Object` doesn't have a colour field. I wouldn't recommend it, but if you want to move forward with this design, you could make a class called ShapeCarParent (used in this case because I see no clear relationship between the two) and have both the classes inherit from that, and then change getColour, like so:

```
public class ShapeCarParent{
  public String colour;
}

public class Car extends ShapeCarParent
public class Shape extends ShapeCarParent

public class Colour {

    public static String getColour(ShapeCarParent item) {
        return item.colour;
    }
}
```

This is still pretty poor style, so you can also use an interface which you then implement in each class.

```
public interface ColorProperties{
    public String getColour();
}
public class Car implements ColorProperites{
    public String getColour() {
        return colour;
    }

}
public class Shape implements ColorProperites{
    public String getColour() {
        return colour;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.